# Force stop will make app's receiver not being called?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, forceclose

I have a service declared in XML that responds to `PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast intent.
It works fine, but I just found out that if I force stop the app, the receiver won't receive anything anymore. It's not being called.

Is this normal? What can I do?

I need to make sure it always responds.

Comment: Hmm, I face the same problem. After debug many times, finally I realize if I use CleanMaster to kill app, my WifiEnabledReceiver (used to keep track of Wifi status) will never received anything.

Comment: Try using Service if activity is not in foreground and schedule alarm to run the service again, which will read the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.1 of Android an application cant receive broadcast intents until its stared once manually. 
Before the first start, the application is considered as "Stopped" by the launcher. (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html under "Launch controls on stopped applications").

If you manually force stop the application, this flag will be set again and you need to relaunch it manually to allow it to receive the events again.

Answer (score 1):

Try add `FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES`

[this FLAG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)
 in your Intent.

Comment: please provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your receiver is registered dynamically by your service, when he is killed the receiver is also.
But if you declare your receiver in XML this should work. (As usual boot receiver)

Comment: In android 3.1+ this is no longer available. Now in android 3.1+ when the app is force stopped, the application will not receive broadcast receivers even they are registered in the manifest file.